# How to get meta`s name

Tags: wordpress

I have read an article '[How Product Attribute are Stored in Database](https://www.webhat.in/article/woocommerce-tutorial/how-product-attribute-are-stored-in-database/)' and I didn't realize how to get the meta name itself. Not meta_key or meta_value (pa_color, pa_size with their values), but 'Size' and 'Color'.

I would like to rename 'Size' to 'T-shirt size' and I have no idea how to do this.

I changed `attribute_name` and `attribute_label` values from `wp_woocommerce_attribute_taxonomies` table, but it had no effect.

Comment: Try changing the column field "name" in the `wp_terms` table, either way. If it's a global attribute I wouldn't complicate things and simply edit it from the wp dashboard by going to: **Products -> Attributes**

Comment: You are right! The attribute is global, that is why I can't see it in `wp_terms` but I easily can edit it from the interface. Do you have any idea how to update a global attribute by raw sql?